# How to handle promise when calling async JS method from C++ using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, asynchronous, promise, emscripten

I have an async JS method something like

```
async Add(_a: number, _b: number): Promise<number> {
    return _a + _b
}

window.Add = Add
```

Normally if I call this function from JS, I would do something like

```
Add(5, 5).then((_result) => {
    console.log(_result)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

How can I achieve this same behavior of handling the promise when calling this JS async function from C++?

Currently, I am doing something like this to call the JS function from C++

```
emscripten::val::global("Add").operator()(5, 5);
```

Comment: Perhaps this describes it: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/asyncify.html

Comment: It automatically `await` any async call defined with the `EM_ASYNC_JS` from the c code: https://web.dev/asyncify/#usage-in-c-c++-with-emscripten